# Why django dependent dropdownn is not working

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

I cant tell where there is an error in my code. It just doesnt work as expected.
My views.py

```
def load_cities(request):
    year_id = request.GET.get('year')
    terms = Term.objects.filter(school=request.user.school).filter(year_id=year_id).order_by('name')
    return render(request, 'city_dropdown_list_options', {'terms': terms})
```

My models.

```
class Year(models.Model):
    
    school = models.ForeignKey(School,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True)

class Term(models.Model):
    school = models.ForeignKey(School,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    year = models.ForeignKey(Year,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True) 

class Exam(models.Model):
    school = models.ForeignKey(School,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    year = models.ForeignKey(Year,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    term = models.ForeignKey(Term,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    form = models.ManyToManyField(FormModel)
```

My forms.py

```
    class NewExamForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Exam
            fields = ("year","term","name","school","form")
            
            widgets = {
                'school':forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":'form-control','value':'','id':'identifier','type':'hidden'}),
                "year":forms.Select(attrs={"class":'form-control'}),
                "name":forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":'form-control'}),
                "form":forms.Select(attrs={"class":'form-control'}),
                
            }
        def __init__(self, school, *args, **kwargs):
            super(NewExamForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            
            
            self.fields['year'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
                queryset=Year.objects.filter(school=school))
    
            self.fields['term'].queryset = Term.objects.none()
    
            self.fields['form'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                queryset=FormModel.objects.filter(school=school),
                widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                required=True)
            
            if 'year' in self.data:
                try:
                    year = int(self.data.get('year'))
                    self.fields['term'].queryset = Term.objects.filter(school=school).filter(year_id=year).order_by('name')
                except (ValueError, TypeError):
                    pass  # invalid input from the client; ignore and fallback to empty City queryset
            elif self.instance.pk:
                self.fields['term'].queryset = self.instance.year.term_set.order_by('name')

The template

<div class="form-group">
        <form method="post" id="examForm" data-cities-url="{% url 'ajax_load_cities' %}" novalidate enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
          {{ form|crispy }}
        </table>
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
        </form>
        
    </div>
```

I have tried but it works only after I select a year and refresh manually with the year selcted, that's when the terms appear.

I tried following the code by Vitor Freitas but couldn't get it working. Anyone with the knowhow to assist.

Comment: You included the form from Vitor Freitas' example, but you did not include the jquery script. If you set up the javascript correctly, it will run when the `year` dropdown changes, and issue an ajax request to update the `terms` dropdown. Without that, the `terms` dropdown won't change unless you refresh it, as you discovered. Work through Vitor's code carefully, and change it to fit your application. If you still have problems, update your question with all of your code, including the javascript, and describe the exact problem you're having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by making corrections on the script as directed by @evergreen.

```
<script>

$("#id_year").change(function () {
  var url = $("#examForm").attr("term-data");
  var yearId = $(this).val();

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: {
      'year': yearId
    },
    success: function (data) {
      $("#id_term").html(data);
    }
  });

});
  </script>
```